# How to organize Ray Tune Trainable class calculations in a k-fold CV setup?

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameters, ray

It looks like the Ray Tune docs push you to write a Trainable class with a `_train` method that does incremental training and reports metrics as a dict. There is some persistance of state through the _load _restore methods.

**TLDR; There is no stated good way to run nested parallel runs based on a config and log the results etc. Does this pattern break the tune flow?**

If you want to use aggregated scores over different train/test pairs (with different models), it the intended pattern that you map (parellel) over the train/test pairs and models inside the `_train` method?

If there is a better place for this question about Tune usage let me know.

Comment: See https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/api_docs/suggestion.html#ray.tune.suggest.Repeater mentioned here https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/7744